# Introductory Set Theory - Image of Set Difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading a proof that shows $f[S_1] \setminus [S_2] \subseteq f[S_1\setminus S_2]$, where $S_1,S_2$ are subsets of $S$. I know that a counter argument can be used to disprove the reverse inclusion but I tried to reverse the implications in given proof and I cannot understand where it goes wrong.

Proof:

$y\in f[S_1] \setminus f[S_2]$

$\leftarrow \exists x∈S1:x \notin S_2:(x,y) \in f$ Definition of Image of Subset under Mapping

$\leftarrow \exists x \in S_1\setminus S2:(x,y)∈f$ Definition of Set Difference

$\leftarrow y∈f[S1\setminus S2]$ Definition of Image of Subset under Mapping

$\square$

Can anyone hint me where the proof goes haywire. I am thinking of the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the easiest counterexample, which is the unique map $f:\{a,b\} \rightarrow \{*\}$ with $S_1=\{a\}$, $S_2$={b}$. Let‘s see, why the proof fails.

First we note that $f(S_1\setminus S_2)=f(S_1)=\{*\}$ while $f(S_1)\setminus f(S_2) = \{*\}\setminus \{*\}=\emptyset$. So if you start with the element $*\in \{*\}$ you find an $x\in S_1\setminus S_2$ with $f(x)=*$, but the last step is indeed wrong, since this doesn‘t mean that $f(x)\in f(S_1)\setminus f(S_2)$.

The problem is that the formulas
$$\exists x\in S_1: (\forall x‘\in S_2: x\neq x‘)\land f(x)=y$$
and
$$\exists x\in S_1: (\forall x‘\in S_2: f(x)\neq f(x‘)) \land f(x)=y$$
are not equivalent. The former classifies the image of the complement, the latter the complement of the images. The second formula implies the first, giving rise to the subset inclusion. But for the other direction you need something like injectivity. The counterexample above is far from being injective.

Answer (score 0):

The proof fails at last step since if we have $∃x∈S_1:x \notin S_2:(x,y)∈f
$ we cannot conclude that $y∈f[S_1]\setminus f[S_2]$. Since there might exists an $x'\in S_2$ such that $f(x')=y$.

Do you think this a valid argument ?

Comment: You are right about that. But to disprove the reverse inclusion, you have to give a counterexample.  Can you think of a function that might fail on this property?

Comment: A constant function mapping all sets to the empty set.